# How to send data from 1 jar to another not on the same machine java

Tags: java, jar

I have absolutely no idea how to do this so I'm just gonna ask. How would I send values from 1 jar (like a boolean) to another jar not on the same computer. I know you could probably do something with SQL but that wouldn't update constantly. What would be the way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways possible:

- Use RPC to send a message
- Use a messaging service like kafka or activeMq
- If latency is not an issue you can better of write to a shared file
  which both JVMs has access to.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RMI (Remote Method Invocation) in Java for that.

I think the best thing you can do is to look at one RMI tutorial to get started like this one:

https://www.javatpoint.com/RMI

Oracle also provides a tutorial on RMI:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

The nice thing about RMI is that it comes with Java out of the box and no extra libraries are needed.

Comment: Does this have so 2 programs can talk to each either, or is it like Client talks to server which talks to other client

Comment: @AZGames Yes, exactly. There is client and a server and there is also a 3rd server which is the rmiregistry which you have to start before you start client and server. Follow the instructions on the Oracle link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html and you will be able to get some communication going.

Comment: Isn't there some easier way to just sent something from client to client, I don't get why you need 2 servers and 1 client or something